# Permament cookies in Phoenix Framework

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to implement a typical "Remember me" functionality on my site which requires a way to create cookies that expire in some far away future. Is there a way to create those in Phoenix Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the cookie a really high `:max_age` value:

http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_cookie/4